# MySQL Display All Date between range altough is no record

Tags: mysql, date

I Have Table xDateList Contain:

```
+---------+
 xDateList 
+---------+
2018-11-01
2018-11-02
2018-11-03
2018-11-04
2018-11-05
```

And Also Table ScanLog

```
--------------------------------------
ID  Name   ScanDate               Code
--------------------------------------
1   John   2018-11-02 07:00:00    IN
1   John   2018-11-02 10:00:00    OUT
1   John   2018-11-04 08:00:00    IN
1   John   2018-11-04 12:00:00    OUT
```

I have tried this but it cannot display all record on xDateList, it only show record on table ScanLog

```
select xDateList.date, 
       scanlog.name, 
       MIN(scanlog.scandate) AS `IN`, 
       MAX(scanlog.scandate) AS `OUT`
from scanlog 
left JOIN xDateList ON xDateList.date = date(scanlog.scandate) 
where scanlog.id='1' 
GROUP BY DATE(scanlog.scandate)
```

I want result like this

```
--------------------------------------------
Date         ID   Name   In         Out
--------------------------------------------
2018-11-01   1    John   
2018-11-02   1    John   07:00:00   10:00:00
2018-11-03   1    John
2018-11-04   1    John   08:00:00   12:00:00
2018-11-05   1    John
```

Thankyou for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the order of tables in the `LEFT JOIN`. Always remember that in order to consider all the rows from a particular table; that particular table should be the left-most table in the Join.

Also, whenever doing a LEFT JOIN, conditions on the right side table should be specified in the `ON` clause; otherwise the conditions in WHERE clause can effectively turn it to INNER JOIN instead.

Also, in this case, the `GROUP BY` should be on the `xDateList.date` to show all the rows corresponding to `xDateList.date` values. And, we need to ensure that all non-aggregated columns in the `SELECT` list are specified in the `GROUP BY` clause as well. Do check: [Error related to only_full_group_by when executing a query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34115174/2469308)

```
SELECT xDateList.date, 
       scanlog.name, 
       MIN(scanlog.scandate) AS `IN`,
       MAX(scanlog.scandate) AS `OUT`
FROM xDateList  
LEFT JOIN scanlog  
  ON xDateList.date = date(scanlog.scandate) AND
     scanlog.id='1' 
GROUP BY xDateList.date, scanlog.name
```

**Result**

```
| date       | name | IN                  | OUT                 |
| ---------- | ---- | ------------------- | ------------------- |
| 2018-11-01 |      |                     |                     |
| 2018-11-02 | John | 2018-11-02 07:00:00 | 2018-11-02 10:00:00 |
| 2018-11-03 |      |                     |                     |
| 2018-11-04 | John | 2018-11-04 08:00:00 | 2018-11-04 12:00:00 |
| 2018-11-05 |      |                     |                     |
```

[**View on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jFQRDyU47toZeSdRMUECta/0)